¿Is there a way to see the LIQUIDITY and other data of a pool, using the raydium sdk?
I have the id of a pool, but I want to obtain the LIQUIDITY, the markers, the price of the coins of those holders, etc.
I know that with dex Screener, you can, but the information is not in real time.
Thanks
